# HK2 using @Named to inject implementations not working

Tags: java, guice, service-locator, hk2

I am trying to learn HK2 to use the service locator pattern. The following is some  code i have written:

```
package org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file;
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Contract;

@Contract
public interface FileReader {
    public void test();
}
```

The above is an interface. The following 2 test implementations are as follows:
    package org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file;

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;

@Service (name="org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file.OcxReaderImpl")
@Singleton
class OcxReaderImpl implements FileReader{
    public void test() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("OCX HelloWorld!!!!"+ ", ");
    }
}
```

And the following is the 2nd implementation:
    package org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file;

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;

@Service (name="org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file.RarReaderImpl")
@Singleton
class RarReaderImpl implements FileReader{
    public void test() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("RAR HelloWorld!!!!"+ ", ");
    }
}
```

And the following class with the main() method to test this:

```
package org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.ServiceLocatorUtilities;

public class Hk2Test {

private static ServiceLocator SERVICELOCATOR = ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator();

@Inject @Named ("org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file.OcxReaderImpl")
public static FileReader fr =SERVICELOCATOR.getService(FileReader.class);

@Inject @Named ("org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file.RarReaderImpl")
public static FileReader fr2 =SERVICELOCATOR.getService(FileReader.class);

public static void main(String argv[]) {

    //FileReader ocxReaderService = SERVICELOCATOR.getService(FileReader.class);
    //ocxReaderService.test();   
    fr.test();
    fr2.test();
  }
}
```

When i run this, the following is the output:

```
 OCX HelloWorld!!!!, 
 OCX HelloWorld!!!!,
```

where i am expecting

```
 OCX HelloWorld!!!!, 
 RAR HelloWorld!!!!,
```

Please advise on what am i doing wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: Use [`getService(FileReader.class, name);`](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator.html#getService%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.annotation.Annotation...%29). Your class `Hk2Test` is not managed. Injections don't work. Anyway you are instantiating it yourself, defeating the purpose of injection

Comment: i changed to use the getService(FileReader.class, name) but got the same result. Can you please elaborate more on 'not managed' part of it

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a chance to test. But you may need to use the `@Named("...")` annotation. Seem the `name` in service does not work for this. Also by managed I mean simply it's not managed by the DI container. You other classes are managed as they are annotated with `@Service`. I don't think simply annotating the `Hk2Test` class will work in this case though. Not sure the reason, could be the static issue, the main class issue, who knows. But create another service class, and try to inject it there (do not instantiate, just declare) and injection should work

Comment: I think in your build you need to use either hk2-metadata-generator or hk2-inhabitant-generator described [here](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b20/inhabitant-generator.html).  Otherwise createAndPopulateServiceLocator will not work properly.  The name field of @Service does work, so I do not think that is the problem

Comment: I did use hk2-inhabitant-generator as a build plugin in my pom.file but it did not work

Comment: Did it produce a file named META-INF/hk2-locator/default?  You might want to look at that to see if the name field is set properly

Comment: no it did not produce any such file, that what is where i am stuck at. not sure why this won;t generate. the project compiles fine and there are no errors

Comment: do you know what dependency i can use for that again, also where do i add it in my pom file

Comment: I just tested again, and yes the `@Service(name="..")` works fine. The META-INF should be in the target/classes after it's generated. If you still don't have it working, can you post the project to github.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you put this XML into your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-inhabitant-generator</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b20</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-inhabitants</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-inhabitants</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: i already did put this xml and it did not generate the meta-inf folder

Comment: Are your java files under src/main/java or src/test/java?  One other thing to try is to put a dependency in your normal dependency section on hk2-metadata-generator.  Maybe that'll give you better luck

Answer (score 0):

Sample with Hk2Utilities. A real time saver!!

```
package org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory;
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;

import gov.va.oia.HK2Utilities.HK2RuntimeInitializer;


@Service
public class Hk2Test {

    @Inject
    @Named("org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file.OcxReaderImpl")
    FileReader fr;

    @Inject
    @Named("org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file.RarReaderImpl")  
    FileReader fr2;

    public void test() {
        fr.test();
        fr2.test();
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        HK2RuntimeInitializer.init("Test", false, "org.swx.nursing.ccquerytool.file" );
        ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance().create("Test");
        Hk2Test app = locator.getService(Hk2Test.class);        
        app.test();
    }
}
```